# Double @ in type

Tags: scala

What is the meaning of double at (@@) as in the example below:

```
trait LowPriorityBijections {

  implicit def fromInjection[A, B](implicit inj: Injection[A, B]): Bijection[A] =
    new AbstractBijection[A, B @@ Rep[A]] {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a type alias declared in the [`com.twitter.bijection`](http://twitter.github.io/bijection/index.html#com.twitter.bijection.package@@@[T,Tag]=Twithcom.twitter.bijection.package.Tagged[Tag]) package.class:

```
/**
 * Tag a type `T` with `Tag`. The resulting type is a subtype of `T`.
 *
 * The resulting type is used to discriminate between type class instances.
 */
type @@[T, Tag] = T with Tagged[Tag]
```

You can also [explore the source](https://github.com/twitter/bijection/blob/develop/bijection-core/src/main/scala/com/twitter/package.scala#L62).

Comment: Also note that `B @@ Rep[A]` means the same as `@@[B, Rep[A]]` - alternative syntax, similar to how there's a normal method call syntax and infix method call syntax.